# React Devtools 4 DOM updates highlights

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

Where is Highlight DOM updates in React Devtools 4.x ?

Up until last week it was still there (was it the old React Devtools 3.x?), and now it is gone.
[image: highlightUpdate]

Is it replaced by "Profiler" tab?

Comment: had to roll back to devtools 3.x (obtained from devtools github project), so can get this functionality again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this on [twitter](https://twitter.com/brian_d_vaughn/status/1162393047352500227), the omission of **Highlight Updates** was deliberate.

Reading the [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/cqx554/introducing_the_new_react_devtools/ex1r9nb/), it seems they are re-evaluating how to signal performance problems caused by re-renders. Till then, they are encouraging you to use the profiler.